# OAuth2 SSO with redirect to React SPA

Tags: reactjs, express, oauth-2.0

I have a client who is using OAuth2 for single sign on with their own login page. Once user is logged in they will be redirected back to my React SPA i'm building.
What I'm trying to find out is a way for my app to integrate with OAuth2 to keep check if user is still signed in. For example say they refresh the app I need a way to check  OAuth2 if user is still authenticated.

Should I use an express server to manage the AUTHORIZATION_CODE returned by the redirect from OAuth2 ?
From what I understand OAuth2 returns a AUTHORIZATION_CODE and STATE in the redirect url.
If so how would I manage this on the express side ? Is there a express plugin to manage this process.

Or could I just bypass using express and just use the Auth0 React SDK to check if user is Authenticated ? I found this example on the auth0 docs. https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-react
Not sure if this would work because of my setup where the login happens from the client login page and redirects back to my app ?

Answer (score 0):

Authorization codes are meant to be exchanged with access tokens. After you exchanged the code with an access token, what you technically need to do is to inspect the token to check whether it's active or not, with active status meaning that the user is logged in. This can be done in a couple of ways, the following are just the ones I can think of:

1. Most conventional way I know is to send an API request to the introspection endpoint while including the access token. The response will tell whether the token is valid and/or active.
2. If the token if in JWT format, it is usually possible to verify the token signature and verify the expiry time after decoding it. Depending on the authorization server, it might be possible to send this token to the introspection endpoint as well.

Unfortunately I can't help with the specifics as the OAuth2 server being used is not mentioned. But if you actually use Auth0 as your authorization server, you can probably use their libraries to help with their OAuth 2.0 flow, such as logins and auth status checks. Otherwise you might need to find another library like [`node-openid-client`](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client) or do it manually as explained.

Comment: Thanks @ionizer I did mention that it’s Auth0 I even posted a link to the front end option. So what you are saying is once I get redirected with the AUTHORIZATION_CODE to my app I can do a call to Auth0 with AUTHORIZATION_CODE  +  client Id + secret  to get the token ?  The question is how do I manage that token on the express side.

Comment: The express server would just act as a BFF for the react SPA

Comment: Ah, you only mentioned about their library, not as the server. As for token exchange, yes basically as you commented, but for frontend you should use authorization code with PKCE flow so you don't need to pass the secret. As for express server, in most cases you just need to pass the access token there from your frontend and use the token as needed, e.g. get active user id through token inspection.

Comment: As I said the login happens on another page as a single sign on. Then I only have access to the AUTHORIZATION_CODE when the redirect to the app happens. So how would I use front end SDK for getting and storing token ?  What happens if the user refreshes the page ? The no longer have access to the token. Would it not be better to have express as a BFF and handle the token in a cookie session ?

Comment: The token should usually be stored within localStorage or sessionStorage. As for the library, a quick look at the docs it seems that it should help with the login flow, persisting the token in the browser and accessing it for api calls to your backend. Unfortunately we should probably discuss about the library usage in another question or issue.